# Can't check for character "-" in string

Tags: c++

I want to check if any one of the elements ot this string is "-" ?

```
  bool End(char work[])
    {
        int stop = strlen(work);
        for(int i = 0;i < stop;i++)
        {
            //c1 = strcmp(work[i],l);
            if(work[i] == "-")
            {
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: remove the `else {return false;}` part, and change the last `return true;` to `return false;`

Comment: use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and it's `find` member or at least [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in the code.

1.As [@Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) pointed out, `"-"` is a `cstring` but `work[i]` returns a char so you would want to compare it with a char as well. So `"-"` should be replaced with `'-'`.

2.The way you write the `return` statements is incorrect. This will also cause a logical error. In your case, provided you have corrected the mistake pointed out by Jarod42, if the first character of the string is not `'-'` then the function returns false, irrespective of whether the string contains the character `'-'` at all.  Change it to this:

```
for( ... ){
    if(work[i]=='-'){
        return true;            
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 4):

`"-"` is a c-string whereas you expect a char.

use `'-'` instead.

And you can rewrite your function as

```
bool End(const char s[])
{
    return std::any_of(s, s + strlen(s), [](char c) { return c == '-'; });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare a single `char`, you need to use the `'-'` literal, instead of `"-"`.

As an alternative, by the way, I'd suggest using `std::string` instead of `char[]`. A modern alternative to this code could be

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool End(std::string const& work)
{
    return std::any_of(begin(work),
                       end(work),
                       [](char c){ return c == '-'; });
}
```

Similarly you can use the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method from `std::string`

```
#include <string>

bool End(std::string const& work)
{
    return work.find('-') != std::string::npos;
}
```